# Proof $I_{n} - \frac{2}{(\lvert v \rvert)^{2}} * vv^{t}$ is an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

How do I proof that $I_{n} - \frac{2}{(\lvert v \rvert)^{2}} * vv^{t}$ is an orthogonal matrix, given that v $\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ an non-trivial vector. I believe I could use the fact that $U * U^t = I_{n}$, but I do not really know.

Comment: yes, use the fact that you know.

Comment: Could you give a hint as to how I should work it out?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For simplicity, define $u = v/|v|$, so that your matrix is $I - 2uu^\top$ and $|u| = 1$. Show that $(I - 2uu^\top)$ is a symmetric matrix, expand (i.e. "FOIL") the product
$$
\left(I - 2uu^\top \right)\left(I - 2uu^\top \right),
$$
and simplify using the fact that $uu^\top uu^\top = u(u^\top u)u^\top = uu^\top$.